# AMPL IDE - simple linear optimization using a data file

Tags: ampl

I am taking my first look at the AMPL IDE and solving a specific linear optimization problem:

```
--- Start of craft.mod ---
var x >= 0; 
var y >= 0; 
minimize cost: 4 * x + 5 * y; 
subject to m1: 9 * x + 15 * y >= 174;
subject to m2 : 1 * x + 6 * y >= 28; 
subject to m3 : 7 * x + 3 * y >= 40;
--- End of craft.mod ---

--- Start of craft.run ---
reset;
model 'craft.mod';
option solver gurobi;
solve;
display x, y, cost;
--- End of craft.run ---
```

Model and the script combined together do the job. In this example there are 2 buyable products that have 3 different components, the problem is to find the optimal combination of these two products so that the amount of every component is sufficient.

However I realize that once I have more products and more components it will be ridiculous to write out all the constraints. Therefore I am trying to create a generalized version which takes data from a separate file and that can be easily expanded to work with as many coefficient as (realistically) needed.

I'm starting with a data file which, as I imagine, should look something like this:

```
--- Start of craft2.dat ---
param:  PROD:   cost :=
        Z1      4
        Z2      5;
param:  COMP:   val1    val2    req :=
        A       9       15      174
        B       1       6       28
        C       7       3       40;
--- End of craft2.dat ---
```

But how should the model look like now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model part you have to work in addition with sets and parameters.

```
set COMPONENTS = {"A","B","C"};
param val1 {COMPONENTS };
param val2 {COMPONENTS };
param req {COMPONENTS };
```

The parameters get then filled in your datapart and can be index with the set in your equations.

```
subject to m {i in COMPONENTS}:
   val1[i] * x + val2[i] * y >= req[i];
```

Same goes for your objective. But since you just have one objective there is probably no need for a dedicated set. It's also possible to define the set contents in the datapart and just write `set COMPONENTS;` in the Modelpart.